# Removing line breaks doesn't work

Tags: c#

So I have this method:

```
public static string ToProperText(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text.Replace("\r\n", ""));

    string lineSeparator = ((char)0x2028).ToString();
    string paragraphSeparator = ((char)0x2029).ToString();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace(lineSeparator, string.Empty).Replace(paragraphSeparator, string.Empty));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text.Replace("a", ""));
    return null;
}
```

When called with some data from the database, this is the output:

```
<p>\r\n Vanaf nu worden de websiteberichten ook <u>automatisch</u> in de Nieuwssectie op het <strong>forum</strong> geplaatst.</p>\r\n
<p>\r\n Vanaf nu worden de websiteberichten ook <u>automatisch</u> in de Nieuwssectie op het <strong>forum</strong> geplaatst.</p>\r\n
<p>\r\n Vanaf nu worden de websiteberichten ook <u>automatisch</u> in de Nieuwssectie op het <strong>forum</strong> geplaatst.</p>\r\n
<p>\r\n Vnf nu worden de websiteberichten ook <u>utomtisch</u> in de Nieuwssectie op het <strong>forum</strong> gepltst.</p>\r\n
```

No matter what I do, the \r\n won't get removed from the string, although other replacements do work. Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the carriage return and the line feed seperately instead of together? oops never mind I guess you are trying to remove the actual character. didn't notice that at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing here.. have you tried:

```
text.Replace("\\r\\n", "")?
```

"\r\n" would replace real line breaks, not the actual text '\r\n':

[What character escape sequences are available?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

Alternatively, duluca's option should work too.

Answer (score 2):

the string is probably escaped already.  Try

```
text.Replace("\\r\\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text.Replace(@"\r\n", ""));
```

Look for the added @ symbol.